# How to apply a JQuery UI Theme to an entire page?

Tags: jquery-ui

I want all elements to have the same look and feel. Right now, all non-JQuery elements look like junk. How do I make sure all HTML elements look like the theme?

The JQuery Theme CSS is the only CSS on the page, yet none of the elements have changed from the browser default (e.g., H1, P, etc).

Edit: I have already included the jquery-ui.js as well in the page.

```html
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.13.2.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.13.2.custom/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.13.2.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
```

Comment: You can simply add the Classes to your elements if you want to theme them.